# mysql query based on sequenced loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have a MySQL query like this

```
SELECT id,seq,text FROM table ORDER BY seq ASC;
```

**ID** | **SEQ** | **text**
***_*__*_*____**
1  |   1     |  one
2  |   4     |  four
3  |   6     |  six

But i need to accomplish table like this

**ID** | **SEQ** | **text**
***_*__*_*____**
1  |   1     |  one
    |   2     |  
    |   3     |  
2  |   4     |  four
    |   5     | 
3  |   6     |  six

I could do it with multiple queries, but that would be gross. I think it's possible with some loop in PHP. The point is that i need to fill the empty rows just with sequence number. Any ideas?

Comment: your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me yet. Can you please explain the second output table a little more?

Comment: Just do the query once, store the result. Then loop through the numbers using a regular for loop, and inside the loop do a check to see if any of the row's SEQ match up. If they do, use that. Otherwise use a blank stand-in row with that SEQ number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve max seq no from Db

```
$query = SELECT max(seq) as max FROM table;
$result = mysql_query();
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$max = $row['max'];
```

then try a loop

```
"SELECT id,seq,text FROM table ORDER BY seq ASC";
for( loop for $seq)
{
   for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
   {
      if($i == $seq)
      {
         /put your display logic for 1 1 one,2 4 four, 3 6 six
      }
      else
      {
         //blank row
      }
   }
}
```

Above is the blueprint for your answer. I hope you'll get the idea.

UPDATE :
Fetch Record from this query

```
$query2 = "SELECT id,seq,text FROM table ORDER BY seq ASC";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
for($j=0;$j<mysql_num_rows($row2);$j)
```

I have explained here what i mean by 
    for( loop for $seq)

Comment: could you explain just a bit this "for( loop for $seq)" part?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are trying to select data what is not in the table and, for me, the best option is use a stored procedure to "create" your output.

I think that could be possible to create a SQL statement that return this data, but will be  inefficient by using functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = getDataAsAnArray();
$newData = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $data ) - 1; $i++ )
{
    $newData[] = $data[ $i ];
    for ( $j = $data[ $i ][ "SEQ" ] + 1; $j < $data[ $i + 1 ][ "SEQ" ]; $j++ )
    {
        $newData[] = array( "ID" => "", "SEQ" => $j, "text" => "" );
    }
}

$newData[] = $data[ $i ];
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to create a temporary table holding all the numbers:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Numbers ( ID int NOT NULL );
```

Then you populate the numbers from e.g: 1 to 100:

```
DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 100;
WHILE idx > 0 DO
  INSERT Numbers VALUES (idx);
  SET idx = idx - 1;
END WHILE;
```

After that you can create a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Numbers
JOIN table on Numbers.ID = table.SEQ
```

Don't forget to drop the table:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE Numbers
```

Oh, and you wrap all of this into a Stored Procedure.

*Note: this is just a mockup. It might have syntax errors. Currently I don't have a mysql setup.*